# Why ESLint throws 'no-unused-vars' for TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

So, I have this piece of code in .ts file:

```
import {MicroEventInterface} from '../Interfaces';

export default class MicroEvent implements MicroEventInterface {

// code
```

And ESLint throws this error:

[image: error]

I have this config for TypeScript in ESLint:

```
typescript: {
    extends: [
        'plugin:@private/private/react' // private rep with React config
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    plugins: [
        '@typescript-eslint',
        'import'
    ],
    settings: {
        'import/resolver': {
            'node': {
                'extensions': [
                    '.js',
                    '.jsx',
                    '.ts',
                    '.tsx'
                ],
                'moduleDirectory': [
                    'node_modules/',
                    'src/'
                ]
            }
        },
        react: {
            createClass: 'createClass',
            pragma: 'React',
            version: '0.14.9'
        }
    }
}
```

So, everything seems like fine, but I can't conquer this error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**UPD:**

Looks like if I `console.log(` --- `, MicroEventInterface);` error disappears. I think, ESLint does not treat `implements` as actual usage.

Comment: ESLint generally throws such error when the imported modules have not been used in the defining scope. Basically, it wants to say, "Why do you even import something when you don't need it".

Comment: @VikasMishra yep, I understand that. But I am actually using it with 'implements' command.

Comment: Implementing something doesn't mean you are using it. Implement just dictates that it conforms (might use) specific modules if required.

Comment: @VikasMishra So, how then may I fix this issue? Should I place my interfaces in the same file with component? Does this BP?

Comment: Add this to ESLint config file
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": [2, {"vars": "local", "args": "after-used"}]
    }
}

Comment: @VikasMishra Nope, does not work me. Still see this error

Comment: Do not use ESLint. Prefer TSLint.

Comment: @Paleo using TSLint over ESLint isn't a valid option as of 2019, as the TSLint project is being deprecated in favor of using ESLint with TypeScript: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534

Comment: Same issue when importing an interface and use it as a variable or return type. e.g. Reacts FunctionComponent. Is there a solution that works?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

*Source: I am the maintainer of the `typescript-eslint` project.*

The latest version of the `@typescript-eslint` tooling now has full support for scope analysis.

So the steps to fix this are now:

- update your versions to at least v4.9.1 of `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`
- update your ESLint version to at least v6.0.0
- update your config to use `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`

  - *Do not* use the base `no-unused-vars` rule - [see this FAQ article in the project](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/troubleshooting#i-am-using-a-rule-from-eslint-core-and-it-doesnt-work-correctly-with-typescript-code).

Restart your IDE and you should now see the correct lint errors.

Comment: what if ESLint  version is ^6.6.0? That is what is expected when we create project with create react app.

Comment: CRA is in the process of updating to a newer version of eslint and plugins. You can try their upcoming v4 release using their `next` tag on NPM.

Comment: @BradZacher - can you please detail the `update your config to use @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` bit?

Should it look like this?
`"rules": {
    "import/first": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"]
  }`

Comment: Try the docs for more info: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md

Comment: On `@typescript-eslint/parser+plugin` v4.14 and `eslint` v7.18, this still occurs for implemented interfaces.

Comment: The github issue tracker is a much better place to discuss bugs. There you'll find a relevant issue that has been addressed and see the fix is due out Monday.

Comment: @JoepBeusenberg yeah same here. Did you figure out a way to resolve the issue?

Comment: Version `4.9.1`?

Comment: @JayCodist - that was the first version with this feature. But it's now some 12 months old. Consider using the latest version published to NPM.

Comment: Even with this adapted, it still complains about a function's args, even when those come from implementing an interface, meaning the fact they're unused is irrelevant.

Comment: @Nyerguds check the documentation. There are options you can use to customise this behaviour.

Comment: @BradZacher But why are they options? These things should automatically be excluded when they come from interfaces.

Comment: @Nyerguds they are options because not everyone wants unused code in their codebase. Most codebases don't design APIs with unnecessary parameters. So you can configure it as you wish based on the code you have. You can configure the ignore pattern to your liking so you can flag intentionally unused variables as desired. Config to how your codebase works.

Comment: @BradZacher happening now in v6

Comment: @Lance what is happening now....?

Comment: the error from the question "ESLint throws 'no-unused-vars' for TypeScript interface" only get the error on v6 not v5

Comment: It's likely a config error in your project. However Stackoverflow comments are NOT a good way to attempt to have discussions about problems. There is a lot of context I need to be able to help you. Consider filing an issue on github so you can provide the information and I can help you find the solution. Help me to help you.

Answer (score 24):

add this to Eslint rules

```
"rules": {
  "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
    2,
    {
      "args": "none"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/eslint/eslint#configuration and https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#args for additional info. Also 2 could be replaced with "error"

Answer (score 20):

Use `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars-experimental` and turn off `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`.

The issue is resolved in the latter version (experimental).

Sample config:

```
// .eslintrc
{
  ...
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars-experimental": "error"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars-experimental is now depreciated

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for me but this does btw

Answer (score 1):

Using the **varsIgnorePattern** Rule

To solve this issue in a pure TypeScript project, I added the following rule to my eslint config file (`.eslintrc.json`). For this particular solution to work, you must follow the convention that interface names begin with an upper case "I".

Incidentally, other artifacts (namely classes) with the first letter of their name being an upper case "I" will also be ignored when considering whether they are used.

### Eslint

```
...
    "rules": {
        ... other rules omitted ...,
        "no-unused-vars": [
            "warn",
            { 
                "vars": "all",
                "varsIgnorePattern": "[I]\\w+"
            }
        ]
    }
...
```

For more information on this rule, see the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars).

Comment: If you don't like the solution, please leave a comment as to why. Just because you don't like the solution, doesn't make it invalid. I did clearly state caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following rule to your `.eslintrc.json` file

```
{
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn",
  }
}
```