# @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars false positive in type declarations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am having a problem with **@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars**.
I have:

```
type SomeType = (name: string) => void;
```

but I get a **@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars** error in the string with type declaration:

> 'name' is defined but never used

Example of type usage:

```
export const LogSomeInfo: SomeType = (name: string) => {
    const a = name;
    console.log(a);
};
```

or:

```
interface CheckboxPropsType {
    value: string,
    onClick(value: string): void
}
```

and eslint breaks at onClick... string, saying:

> value is defined but never used.

This occurs even if the type is assigned correctly and the actual onClick handler uses the value.

What's wrong with this rule and why is it triggered in this case? Why does eslint recognize type declaration for functions in types/interfaces as regular functions? Is it a problem with my eslint config?

**"eslint": "^7.7.0",**
**"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.6.1",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^9.0.0",**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "react-hooks", "react"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "object-curly-newline": 0,
    "import/named": ["error"],
    "indent": ["error", 4],
    "react/jsx-indent": ["error", 4],
    "comma-dangle": ["error", "never"],
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "react/jsx-fragments": "off",
    "arrow-body-style": "off",
    "object-curly-spacing": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": ["error", 4, {"SwitchCase": 1}],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "no-undef": "error",
    "react/jsx-indent-props": ["error", 4],
    "max-len": ["error", { "code": 120 }],
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: why eslint-plugin 3.6.1 and parser 4.0.1? have you tried to update both to the same version (e.g. 4.0.1)?

Comment: Ran into a different issue with the same symptoms.

We were using `no-unused-vars` instead of `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`. Upgrading @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser to 4.9.0 and adding the following to .eslintrc solved this problem:


`"no-unused-vars": 0, "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { argsIgnorePattern: "^_" }]`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Similar question asked earlier check: [Why ESLint throws 'no-unused-vars' for TypeScript interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807329/why-eslint-throws-no-unused-vars-for-typescript-interface)

Disable `'@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 0` rule and instead use `"strict": true`, `"noUnusedLocals": true`, and `"noUnusedParameters": true`, in tsconfig.json

Comment: Yes. May be it's correct solution.
You can disable this rule, and add to tsconfig --noUnusedLocals and --noUnusedParameters, or you can add @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars-experimental to eslintrc. Both ways solve the problem

Comment: `no-unused-vars-experimental` was experimental, and has since been deprecated. It will be removed in the next major - do not use it. Up to you if you want to use TS's built in unused checks or the eslint rule. The TS checks will block your build, so many people don't like them. See my answer below for how to fix your eslint config.

Comment: How will build get blocked? If you are fulfilling the strict rules

Comment: TypeScript emits by default as long as the file is syntactically valid. `--noEmitOnError` is not the default.

Comment: Agree! with @AluanHaddad

Comment: Sure it's the default - but most user configs I've seen specifically reconfigure to not emit on error so they don't test on weird code that isn't correct. This is why so many users prefer _not_ to use the TS option - because it blocks their development.

Comment: For me, changing moving 'eslint:recommended' higher up in the "extends" array of .eslintrc.json solved the issue

Answer (score 42):

*Source: I am the maintainer of the `typescript-eslint` project.*

If you update your versions of `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` to v4.1.0, you will be able to use the latest changes which make `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` work properly for all cases.

[Here's a typescript-eslint playground which shows the config and the examples working as intended.](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.1.6&showAST=es&fileType=.ts&code=FAehAJFBycDsHtwFMBOy7IM7AC4E8AOi4AynALaIAqBRAvOABQwCGFAXOBtsgJYwDmASnC0AfOABucHgBMA3MEQAPfOmzgAxnBhdwAGTj9SFAJIwAZnA7GqNEYxbtO3PkJHiA3sHCbtu5vaOiAo%2BWjpwADaIAHQRhgzMggoAvgqgENDKhBrYiDLgAK4wBRh5ksyYSKjowHy5yObMGkQAwgAWiBoA1gBGcEoACmj4GNSE4F4%2BYFCwCChomN7lEQWIHFy8AgA0S9PQ8FULWD7aLRE83QwSzCtrzptCHFKywMlAA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQHYHsBaWXWZRAE0IDcBDaVDSfAMxcgBpxtIABAFwCeABxQBjaAEth-QiniTc-APQFipclToN0URNGj5okbgF8QpoA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA&tokens=false)

---

As an aside - using v3.x of the plugin but v4.x of the parser will put you into a really weird state with undefined and unsupported behaviour.

You should make sure you are always using the same version of *both* packages, as each version is released together.

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same issue, now it works after upgrading those 2 libs from 4.0.1 to 4.4.1.

Comment: This is the better solution today.  Confirm working on 4.20.0

Comment: I am on version `4.22.1` and am still getting the warnings. Is there any additional configurations required to disable linting on function parameters within `Types` or `Interfaces`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if both packages need to be used in the same version, why not combine them into a single package? Is there a reason for making them as two separate packages?

Comment: It provides a better config experience due to how ESLint does shorthands. You configure lint rules as `@typescript-eslint/<rule-name>` and the parser as `@typescript-eslint/parser`. If we merged them then we'd have to go with the `eslint-plugin` name (or else the rule config would be awful), so your parser would be `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`; which is weird... Also the rules will mostly work with the babel parser, so there's not a hard requirement to use our parser. Also just nice from a codebase maintenance pov to keep the two different packages separate. So yeah - many reasons.

Comment: I have both on version `4.29.0` and I'm still facing this issue.

Comment: Seeing this issue on 4.6.1

Comment: @Garrett - update to the latest version. `4.6.1` is somewhere in the order of 10 months old

Comment: Still getting a false positive with `5.2.0` which is the current version as of this writing. I should also mention that I am using `@typescript-eslint/*` inside a Vue project.

Comment: Stackoverflow comments are not a good place to discuss or report bugs for obvious reasons. Please create a repro and file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I'm confused, how is this still an issue 1 year after Brad's post? Also getting the false positive unused-vars warning today for a function type with both package versions being 5.4

Comment: I'm using 5.4.0 and this solution produces inconsistent results. It fixed properties getting flagged in interfaces, but now does not flag *actual* unused variables. It also still flags generic declarations like <T> in interfaces and classes. I had to turn the entire feature off.

Comment: For people that are having issues and even downvoting my response - please file an issue on github with your config so I can help you - https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint. Downvoting / commenting with "it's not working" is pretty useless for getting your issue resolved. --- I'm not joking when I say that I want to help you resolve your issue. If it's a bug I'll fix it. If it's a config issue I'll help you correct it. Help me to help you by filing an GH issue with your code + config.

Comment: The rule is working properly for all cases we know of!

Here are is our playground showing a few examples:
https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.5.2&sourceType=module&code=C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFAFAOwIZIBcUAzsAE4CWOA5gJRToB8UAbnJQCYDcAUBAA8wccsCgBjODjJQAYjmLwkqSI2z4ipCtXqMWGiH344ArgigBZEAFFT5gN5QAgmoCMUAL78hIsdWAQ5ABmeOLQAMIAFhDiANYARnACAArkcGAkKtD2vFB5bHgANiYQxFa2ZgB0TgA0uflS4YWUcVisRSXEZFS0dMTsXLxevP6BIWFQAHJwwACqJBCc7vZeoKrTcwucAExqK3wQdlMz84sAzFArQA&rules=N4IgAgLgngDgpgZwMYCcCWMIFpEBs0B2EA9AQPZYCuBlCcAJlgG4CGKCIAXCHCimShABfIA&tsConfig=N4XyA

Comment: @BradZacher your demo shows errors now in 6.2.1

Comment: @CihadTurhan Those errors are fully expected errors because they are unused things!!!

Comment: @BradZacher Now it works as it should – showing errors from eslint. When I tried, it gave errors related to installing dependencies. I guess it was temporary thing

Answer (score 8):

Just make sure you have the latest version of the following:

- typescript-eslint
- @typescript-eslint/parser
- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

in your **.eslintrc.js** make sure you have the following lines added to **rules** section:

```
  "no-unused-vars": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option to fix this is to add `typescript-eslint` to your `extends` and remove it from `plugins`:

```
extends: [
  `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
]
```

You can then also remove `parser: @typescript-eslint/parser` since by extending it, the plugin will handle all of this for you under the hood. You can still override some rules if needed:

```
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['off'],
  },
```