# Failed to update react-scripts

Tags: eslint, create-react-app, react-scripts

I have a react application that was created with create-react-app and is using react-scripts version 3.4.2. The app works great but when I run eslint against it I get many invalid no-unused-vars errors. By invalid I mean that when I go to the file that variable is actually being used.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63798580/8693289) it seems the issue is related to @typescript-eslint/parser and @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin. So I went ahead and executed `npm list @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` on my app and this is what I get:

```
myapp@0.1.0 /Users/diego/myapp/client
└─┬ react-scripts@3.4.2
  ├─┬ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0
  │ └── @typescript-eslint/parser@2.34.0 deduped
  ├── @typescript-eslint/parser@2.34.0
  └─┬ eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
    ├── @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0 deduped
    └── @typescript-eslint/parser@2.34.0 deduped
```

As seen all occurrences of the two potentially conflictive libraries are included by react-scripts app and that is why I am trying to update it.

I tried updating to 4.0.3 and when I do that eslint starts to work fine (those incorrect no-unused-vars are gone) but my app is unresponsive (I click on different buttons and/or links and nothing happen). The only error I see in the console after the update is this one:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
```

I was searching this error and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368760/react-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined). The error is the same maybe not what the developer describes but reading through the answers I see many of them point to react-scripts as the root cause and that maches my scenario.

I tried some of the solutions in that question, in particular method 1 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452191/8693289) (I did not try method 2  because I am not sure if adding craco is what I want) and the solution from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70677211/8693289) too but they do not work.

I also tried updating to react-scripts version 5 but I get A LOT of errors.

Is someone facing this issue or at least has some clue that could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message that you shared seems to be related to a bug with `react-error-overlay`.

`react-scripts` 4.0.3. uses `react-error-overlay` 6.0.9. However, 6.0.10 is marked as a patch, so npm uses 6.0.10 instead of 6.0.9, but 6.0.10 is not compatible with 6.0.9.

On the other hand, `react-scripts` 5 does not use `react-error-overlay`, but might be causing breaking changes with your other packages, hence the other errors.

You can find more information about the `react-error-overlay` bug in these issues on the CRA repository:

- [Hot Reload Fails, DOM adds an additional iframe containing entire
  contents of the html DOM element #11880](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11880)
- [Is this the bug of react-error-overlay? #11773](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773)
- [v5 Regression react-error-overlay build - Uncaught ReferenceError:
  process is not defined #11771](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11771)

Here's a possible solution with `react-scripts` 4.0.3.:

1. In your project's `package.json` file:

- In `dependencies`, ​set the `react-scripts` version to 4.0.3.
- Under `dependencies`, in `resolutions`, add `react-error-overlay` 6.0.9.
- In `devDependencies`, add `react-error-overlay` 6.0.9.

```json
"dependencies": {
  ...
​  "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
  ...
},
"resolutions": {
  ​"react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
},
...
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
  ...
}
```

2. Delete your project's `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file.
3. Run `npm install`.
4. Run `npm install react-error-overlay@6.0.9`.

Comment: Sorry  for  the late response and thanks a lot for the answer. It worked. Just one observation, I  just needed the resolutions field, there was no need for me to add it to devDependencies or install it as you said in step 4.