# ESLint - "no-unused-vars" on function parameters within TypeScript Types/Interfaces

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am currently getting a eslint warning on function parameters within `Types` or `Interfaces`.

Doing the following:

```js
type Test = {
  fn: (param: string) => void
}
```

Results in the following warning:

```js
'param' is defined but never used. Allowed unused args must match /^_/u.
```

Here's what my `.eslintrc.json` looks like:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "tsconfig.json"
  },
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off"
  }
}
```

Package versions:

```
"eslint": "^7.23.0"
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.1"
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.1"
```

Similar questions have been asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807329/why-eslint-throws-no-unused-vars-for-typescript-interface/63798664#63798664) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63767199/typescript-eslint-no-unused-vars-false-positive-in-type-declarations), but the provided answers do not seem to be doing it for me.

Any suggestions as to what could be happening?

Comment: I might be wrong, but probably restart your IDE. Specially, with VSCode, I have seen stale errors until I restart the IDE. It may not help, but may worth a try after you have done this https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md#how-to-use

Comment: @Nishant yeah I tried that but no luck :(

Comment: Doing what's on the link just converts what I'm getting from a `warning` to an `error`

Answer (score 15):

I've solved it this way, put these two lines in rules in the eslint configuration file.

```
"no-unused-vars": "off",
"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"]
```

Comment: for more info see: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the `no-unused-vars` globally in your eslint config, you could set it to the line by placing this comment just above it:

```
 // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

or to the entire file, just add this comment on the top:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the `no-unused-vars` rule to ignore arguments named `param` by adding this line to your `.eslintrc.json` rules: `"no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "params"}]`. See the docs: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern